# <logic:iterate question

Tags: java, jsp, struts

I need to pull all teh messages from a table and display on the jsp page. I have the code like below:
I have the list of messages stored as :
SimpleStringVO string value: Welcome to the XYZ Tool homepage. ,SimpleStringVO string value: Here you can enter your account number ,SimpleStringVO string value:               ,SimpleStringVO string value: thank you

When I tried to display this in jsp page, the message is not formated as it is stored. "thank you" comes immediately after the 2nd string. I need to display the space string and then the "thank you" string. (3rd string has just spaces) My code in Jsp is like this :

```
  <td><logic:iterate name="AllNewsCashe" id="news" type="com.fw.valueobject.SimpleStringVO"> 
          <bean:write name="news" property="stringValue"/> 
          </logic:iterate> 
        </td>
```

how to display thise messages as it is without formating ?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to force a space in HTML, you will need to store it as `&nbsp;` instead of `" "`. However, since are you using `bean:write` tag, you can probably use `filter` property  to retain `" "`:-

```
<bean:write name="news" property="stringValue" filter="false" />
```

Here's the description of `filter` from [Struts documentation](http://struts.apache.org/1.2.x/userGuide/struts-bean.html#write):-

> If this attribute is set to true, the
>   rendered property value will be
>   filtered for characters that are
>   sensitive in HTML, and any such
>   characters will be replaced by their
>   entity equivalents.

Comment: thanks. here I need to give a lots of &nbsp; to move the string a little. Also database maintenance folks should know about &nbsp;. Is there any other in JSP itslef ??? what does IndexID do ?